# How inject service in component

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a component and service, I try to inject service (ListUserService) in component. 
I import the service, I request it and I get an error, when I delete the service it works well, what is the error?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ListUserService} from './list-user.service';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-list-user',
      templateUrl: './list-user.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./list-user.component.scss'],
      providers: [ListUserService]
    })
    export class ListUserComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(private listUserService: ListUserService) {
            console.log(this.listUserService);
        }
    }
```

and this is the service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListUserService {
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/user/getUsers/`)
            .subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }
}
```

this is the error:
**ERROR**

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ListUserService -> HttpClient]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ListUserService -> HttpClient]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!

this is the file app.module.ts

```
 import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ListUserComponent} from './list-user/list-user.component';
import {ListUserService} from './list-user/list-user.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, ListUserComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
    providers: [
        HttpClient,
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        ListUserService,
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy}
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You have failed to add HttpClientModule in imports of `app.module.ts`***

```
import { ListUserComponent } from './list-user/list-user.component';
import { ListUserService } from './list-user/list-user.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ListUserComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
      ListUserService,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: HttpClientModule ? how add that

Comment: import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that missing import .

Comment: @VivekanandanSakthivelu if you don't mind, please update your answer to include the import. That may help some other users facing the same issue.

Comment: @sebaferreras sure

Answer (score 0):

Add your Service to the `providers: [ListUserService]` in your app.module.ts

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules

EDIT: HttpClient must be added to `providers: [ListUserService, HttpClient]` aswell as `import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: occur the same problem

Comment: if you created the service while your dev server was running, try restarting it.

Comment: Oh I see, your problem is not the ListUserService but HttpClient. You have to add this aswell in the providers.